# Ethiopic unicode appear as square boxes on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to develop a kids educational iOS (iPhone/ipad) app that displays Ethiopic unicode (i.e. Ethiopian chars) on a UILable; but what I am seeing is only a square box for each char. For example, to display the first Ethiopic char (i.e. unicode 0x1260), I am writing the following code:

```
myLbl.text = @"\u1260";
```

But as I said, on the iPhone simulator, what I am seeing is a square box. Similarly, I tried to write pi and some other Greek characters and they all work fine. This code, for example, displays the pi ( π ):

```
myLbl.text = @"\u03c0";
```

Why do the Ethiopic unicode appear as square boxes? What am I missing?

I greatly appreciate your replies,

-Teddy

P.S. I use xcode 4.4.1, run the app only on the iOS simulator (not on a device)

Answer (score 1):

It will only work if the font you are using actually contains the glyphs for those characters. Simply try a different font.